# How to make Google recognize language for a multilingual website?

Tags: seo, google, html, google-search, multilingual

A few weeks ago I implemented a translation functionality for my company website. The website now offers content in french and English and I took the time to look on various guides on the internet on methods how this can be done in a friendly way so that my rankings would not be affected as a result.

Here is what I did:

- I did set a response header: `Content-Language:en` and `Content-Language:fr`
- My URLs are formatted as: `www.website.com/en/...` and `www.website.com/fr/...`
- My HTML tag is set with a lang attribute: `<html lang="en">` and `<html lang="fr">`
- `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="EnglishPageUrl">` on French pages.
- `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="frenchPageUrl">` on English pages.

But Google keeps referring to some English pages when I'm doing a search on Google.fr, knowing that the website was first only available in English.

Is that normal? Do I have to wait still, it has been now almost one month, I thought it would be okay...?

Thank you.

Comment: The rel=alternate tags: the spec requires referencing the current page as an alternative of itself. Are you doing that?

Comment: @GDav No, thank you I didn't see this, I thought it was better to do not display a reference to the current page, it appears I was wrong!

Comment: No problem. Incidentally, with the exception of their rel=alternate markup, Google claim not to use anything other than language processing to target content, which is odd if you're searching in French on google.fr for content that exists in French.

Comment: @GDav Google doesn't use code level methods of identifying the language of a page. It suggests keeping the language of a page to one and not using two languages on a page. See my edits to John's answer below.

Comment: @Anagio Yes, that's what I said, though as I noted, this is "with the exception of their rel=alternate markup". I suppose I could've been clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Google Webmaster Tools Support page on [Multi-region and multilingual sites](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192)

> **Managing multilingual versions of your site**
>
> Make sure the page language is obvious
>
> Google uses only the visible content of your page to determine its
> language. We don’t use any code-level language information such as
> Lang attributes. You can help Google determine the language correctly
> by using a single language for content and navigation on each page,
> and by avoiding side-by-side translations. Translating only the
> boilerplate text of your pages while keeping the bulk of your content
> in a single language (as often happens on pages featuring
> user-generated content) can create a bad user experience if the same
> content appears multiple times in search results with various
> boilerplate languages.
>
> Use robots.txt to block search engines from crawling automatically
> translated pages on your site. Automated translations don’t always
> make sense and could be viewed as spam. More importantly, a poor or
> artificial-sounding translation can harm your site’s perception.
>
> Make sure each language version is easily discoverable
>
> Keep the content for each language on separate URLs. Don’t use cookies
> to show translated versions of the page. Consider cross-linking each
> language version of a page. That way, a French user who lands on the
> German version of your page can get to the right language version with
> a single click.
>
> Avoid automatic redirection based on the user’s perceived language.
> These redirections could prevent users (and search engines) from
> viewing all the versions of your site.
>
> Carefully consider your choice of URL
>
> Google uses the content of the page to determine its language, but the
> URL itself provides human users with useful clues about the page’s
> content. For example, the following .ca URLs use fr as a subdomain or
> subdirectory to clearly indicate French content:
> `http://example.ca/fr/vélo-de-montagne.html`
> `http://fr.example.ca/vélo-de-montagne.html`
>
> Signaling the language in the URL may also help you to discover issues
> with multilingual content on your site.
>
> It’s fine to translate words in the URL, or to use an
> Internationalized Domain Name (IDN). Make sure to use UTF-8 encoding
> in the URL (in fact, we recommend using UTF-8 wherever possible) and
> remember to escape the URLs properly when linking to them.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake in the **hreflang="en"** in the following, it must be **hreflang="fr"** on English pages:
 on English pages.

Comment: Thanks, that's corrected, but you should have posted this as a comment or better, edit my question, but you may not have reputation enough...